# How can I detect when increasing the size TDictionary

Tags: delphi, generics

I use TDictionary to handle large volumes of data. How can I detect the moment when the size increases TDictionary?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to detect when the underlying private storage is grown, then you cannot. That is handled by the private methods `SetCapacity` and `Grow`, and the class provides no external hook.

You can detect key and value modifications using the `OnKeyNotify` and `OnValueNotify` events. The `OnKeyNotify` event fires with notification parameter of `cnAdded` when a new key is added.

Comment: Actually its also done in the Grow method which is triggered from Add and AddOrSetValue - DRY anyone? -.-

Comment: @StefanGlienke Sigh. Clearly `Grow` should call `SetCapacity`. And look at how one uses clear and easy to understand `*2`, and the other uses cryptic `shl 1`.

Comment: In this case, Grow is the internal, optimised version, which is only called wtih clear preconditions, so I don't think this is DRY. SetCapacity does more than just double the capacity and rehash, it also performs some checks on the input value, which Grow does not need. OK, one uses `shl 1` and the other `* 2`, but otherwise, I think this makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Rudy Premature opt. The rehash swamps the checks. But even if you wanted that prem opt, it could still be done with an internal uncheck DoSetCapacity. DRY is important. This code fails.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis SetCapacity is private and TDictionary does not have a Capacity property so this also is only internal. Also in other cases (TList, TQueue) Grow internally calls SetCapacity.

Comment: SetCapacity does some checks that Grow does not need, so I still think the code of Grow does not violate DRY. A dictionary is not a list or a queue, so what other containers do doesn't matter much.

Comment: @David: I don't think so. Perhaps SetCapacity could call Grow, but Grow should certainly not have to call SetCapacity. But SetCapacity uses a different loop too. So no, sorry, it is not a violation of DRY at all, even if at a short glance, it may look like it. Grow and SetCapacity don't do the same things here, and neither is a, er... "superset" of the other either.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis A skilled programmer would have no difficulty arranging this better

Comment: I don't see how or why. It is a very short routine, and I see no need to jump through hoops to rearrange this for no benefit at all. Both routines serve different purposes, and I would have done the same. AFAIK, this was done by Barry Kelly, who is without any doubt a skilled programmer.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Proof by reputation?

Comment: Proof? I never mentioned "proof". But if you want it, read the code, there is the proof that Grow does not do the same as SetCapacity, so there is no repetition. You mentioned that a skilled programmer would have arranged things differently and I merely noticed that the author is such a skilled programmer, and he did not arrange this differently. Neither would I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Delphi there is the **Capacity** property:

```
property Capacity: Integer read GetCapacity write SetCapacity;
```

But you still don't get to know when the object grows capacity on its own.

You can though set the Capacity large enough to cover your needs, Then use the **TrimExcess** method to set the capacity to actual number of entries.